# compare two files of different formats in python

Tags: python, json, parsing, search

What is the best way to compare two different files in different formats in Python.

```
File1: strings
    Type=Test Id=00001 Time=7:41pm Desc=Test Qt=1
    Type=Update Id=34234 Time=7:42pm Desc=ABC Qt=1
    Type=New Id=12345 Time=7:42pm Desc=ABC Qt=1

File2: json
    {"Type":"New","Id":"12345","Time":"17:42:43","Title":"ABC","Quantity":1}
```

Each file has 20,000+ lines and won't match up line for line, so line 100 in file 1 will not be the same as line 100 in file 2.

At the moment i parse out the Id in file 1 and search the entirety of file 2 for that Id and then break when it finds it. However, as I get further into file 2, it takes longer to parse each entry.

I am reasonably confident that if I find Id=12345 in file 2 that Id=12346 will be after that in the file. So i guess that the second entry from file 1 should start searching file 2 the first entry it finds.

```
def parse_file1(self, file1, file2):
    for i, log_line in enumerate(open(file1, "r").readlines()):
        mydict = dict(item.split("=") for item in line.split(" "))
        if "New" in mydict['Type']:
            id = mydict['Id']
            result = self.parse_file2(id, file2)

def parse_file2(self, id, file2):
    result = 0
    for i, line in enumerate(open(file2, "r").readlines()):
        fileOneDict = json.loads(line)
            if str(fileOneDict['Type']) == "New":
                if id == str(fileOneDict['Id']):
                    result += 1
                    break
    return result
```

Comment: Read in your file of strings, parse each line into a dict, make a list of those dicts and save the list as JSON. Read the JSON file and re-save it to ensure that the formatting is equivalent to the first step. Then use `difflib` to compare the two files.

Comment: There is no need to re-read file 2 completely for each search. Parse the second file and using the id from each entry as key, create a dictionary where the entry value is the dictionary of the line from file2. Then scan through file 1 and finding the matching id from file 2 in the dictionary is O(1), i.e. constant time. Then you can compare the entries.

Comment: And if you still have problems, post a minimal version your code which shows the problem *including* some data initialisations of sample data into your question as a [mre], so anyone can, _without adding anything_, reproduce the problem you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear from the code you show that you are only interested in those entries in both files that specify `Type=New` and `"Type": "New"` respectively. If so, then I would read the file specified by `file2` one line at a time (no need to read the entire file into memory) and for those dictionary instances that have for key 'Type' the value `New`, I would collect these dictionary values in another dictionary, `file2_dict`, whose key is the 'Id' value of the dictionary converted to a string. This allows me to find the dictionary given an id as an O(1) operation. I would then process each line of the file specified by `file1` and if its type is 'New' I would use its 'Id' value to look up the corresponding `file2` dictionary in `file2_dict`. If it exists I then can do whatever further comparisons on the two dictionary entries I wish:

```py
import json

class Comparer:
    def __init__(self, file1, file2):
        self.file1, self.file2 = file1, file2

    def parse_files(self):
        file2_dict = {}
        
        with open(self.file2, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                d = json.loads(line)
                if d['Type'] == 'New':
                    str_id = str(d['Id'])
                    # store this in file2_dict keyed by str_id
                    file2_dict[str_id] = d
            
        with open(self.file1, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                d1 = dict(item.split("=") for item in line.split())
                #if 'New' in d['type']:
                if d1['Type'] == 'New':
                    d2 = file2_dict.get(d1['Id'])
                    if d2:
                        self.compare(d1, d2)

    def compare(self, d1, d2):
        """ Compare two dictionary entries from file1 and file2 """
        pass

Comparer('test1.txt', 'test2.txt').parse_files()
```